# Cookies coming in Response Headers but not showing up in document.cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I am using Node.js as my runtime for a service that I'm developing.

Responses are sending cookies to be stored in the browser but when I open the `Resources Tab` in the Chrome debugger, no cookies are available.

Even `document.cookie` gives `""` (Empty string).

[image: Request headers]
[image: Cookies]

I tried the same in Firefox as well but no use.

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://something.something.com");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-Api-Signature, X-Api-AuthToken");
    next();
};
```

Comment: You should most definitely provide us with some code. Particularly where you declare and start the app, as well as where you're setting a cookie in a route's response.

Comment: Are you using CORS? it has it's own set of rules when it comes to handling cookies.

Comment: @KevinB Yes I am using CORS.

Comment: @Seth Added code for the middleware being used for setting up cors

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're ever setting a cookie in that middleware function. Only headers. Can you provide the code, redacted if necessary, in which you actually set a/the cookie? e.g. `res.cookie('name ', val, {// optional settings});`